# Rails: Setting up a gravatar image for user profile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, profile, gravatar

I'm working through the [Michael Hartl's](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-up#sec-a_gravatar_image%20%22Michael%20Hartl%27s) Ruby on Rails Tutorial to add a Gravatar image to the user profile.

Here is my code:

```
#app/views/users/show.html.erb

<% provide(:title, @user.name) %>

<h1>
  <%= gravatar_for @user %>
  <%= @user.name %>
</h1>
```

And helper:

```
#app/helpers/users_helper.rb

module UsersHelper

  # Returns the Gravatar (http://gravatar.com/) for the given user.
  def gravatar_for(user)
    gravatar_id = Digest::MD5::hexdigest(user.email.downcase)
    gravatar_url = "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/#{gravatar_id}"
    image_tag(gravatar_url, alt: user.name, class: "gravatar")
  end
end
```

And then I have used update_attributes to update the user in the database:

```
$ rails console
>> user = User.first

>> user.update_attributes(name: "Example User",
?> email: "user@myapplication.com",
?> password: "password",
?> password_confirmation: "password")
=> true
```

So after that when I access the show page of user profil, I only have the original gravatar image, but not the custom gravatar associated with the user email.

What can be wrong?

Thanks,

Comment: Does the email `user@myapplication.com` have an account at http://www.gravatar.com? And if it's a new account, it make take a few minutes to come through.

Comment: No this was just an example, I used my real email adress which have a custom photo on gravatar...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the email you provided must have an account on gravatar so you can render the custom image ,if it's not registered in gravtar ,it will provide the default image for you ,try with registered emails